# form post action into php var

Tags: php, forms

Im in this page: website.php?page=5 and in this page I have this form:

```
<form method="POST" action="website.php?page=<?php echo $pagenumber; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="goto" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="goto" />
</form>
```

If I write something like 3 into the text field and press the goto button (if isset.... my php code get the number and upload into the $pagenumber var)

But the new page isn't the **website.php?page=3** what I want. The new page is **website.php?page=**   (there is no number)  .and if I press again then goes it to the right page.

I think in the first press when i do the **$pagenumber** isn't declared. Only when i press second.

How can I fix it? I must use this way i cant use session, cookie etc.

```
                <?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    $kitkeresek = $_POST['goto'];
                                $becsuletemw = "SELECT * FROM adatok WHERE nev = '$kitkeresek'";
                            $becsuletem2w = mysql_query($becsuletemw);
                            while( $becsuletem3w = mysql_fetch_array($becsuletem2w))
                            $becsuletemw = $becsuletem3w["becsulet"];

                    $valllamiw = mysql_query("SELECT  becsulet FROM adatok WHERE becsulet > '$becsuletemw' ");
                    $rowsw = mysql_num_rows( $valllamiw );
                    $kitkeresekw = $rowsw + 1 ;
                    $intvizsgalat= $kitkeresekw/10;
                        if (is_int($intvizsgalat))  
                                { $pagenumber = $intvizsgalat - 1 ; }  
                            else  
                                {$pagenumber = floor($kitkeresekw/10); } ; 
                } 
            ?>
```

Comment: Can you include the part where you assign `$pagenumber`?

Comment: how and where do you declare `$pagenumber` variable before this form? show us.

Comment: I added it to my question.

Comment: Can you clear up your question?  I don't quite understand what your goal is.  Do you want your form on submit to `POST /website.php?page={the number you entered}`? or do you just want the URL to show `/website.php?page={int}`  If it's the first you'll need to use some Javascript to capture the value of your input field and modify the form's action before submitting.  If it's the latter, you'll need to redirect to the new URL from your PHP script.

Comment: finally work... I delete the action in the submit button and i put a redirect link in the end of the php code.

Comment: here is a simplified code what i modify and use.
    `<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
      $pagenmr2 = $_POST['oldalkeres'];
      
      echo "<script>";
      echo "window.location.href =\"website.php?page=".$pagenmr2."\";";
      echo "</script>";
     } ;
    ?>
    <form method="POST" >
     <input type="text" name="oldalkeres" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Keresés" />
    </form>`

Answer (score 2):

When you do this :

$intvizsgalat= $kitkeresekw/10;

$intvizsgalat is float, even if the result is int, because it is the result of a division.

You can try var_dump($intvizsgalat) to confirm

try something like this:

```
$floatParts = $intvizsgalat - floor(intvizsgalat);
if ($floatParts == 0) {
//
} else { 
//
}
```

Comment: $intvizsgalat= $kitkeresekw/10;
There is 2 different result. a: integer b: decimal numbers and i check this. but not this part is my problem. When i press the "goto" button the action link didnt upload the $pagenumber variant only if I press twice :S

Comment: Ok, so add a hidden input in your form like this
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pageNumber; ?>" />